# Materialize Preloader bar stuck when rendering React Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, materialize

I am currently using the `Materialize preloader` (`Indeterminate` type) from http://materializecss.com/preloader.html

So how I am currently using it is:

My redux `state` object looks something like this:

```
state = {
    ...
    showProgressBar: true/false
}
```

Now when I click the button associated with fetching some api objects, I trigger an `action` that makes the `showProgressBar: true` and when the item is fetched, in the `reducer` I make it `showProgressBar: false`.

This toggling works perfectly. However, the time between it becoming *visible* and going back to *invisible*, the `preloader` just gets stuck. i.e. It does not do its animation.

What could the possible reason for this be?

Comment: so it can hide / show, but isn't animated?

Comment: could you provide more code??

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set `className="indeterminate"`

Comment: Also are you using a `preloader` (circle) or progress bar ?

Comment: Hey! So I am using the `className="indeterminate"` progress bar(not the circle). Somehow the circle works but the bar get stuck in between animation.

Comment: can you provide your implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## State Updates May Be Asynchronous

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  showProgressBar: !prevState.showProgressBar 
}));
```

See: [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

## Import

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

## Create component

```
function Preloader() {
  return (
     <div className="progress">
       <div className="indeterminate"></div>
     </div>
  )
}
```

## Toggle component

```
import Preloader from '/my-components/preloader`
...
{ this.state.showProgressBar && <Preloader /> }
```

See: [working example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kq4_2AIzWm5Fm56BoYr)

## React-materialize

You should use [react-materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io)

> Material design for react, powered by materializecss

```
import {Preloader} from 'react-materialize'

export default () => (
    <Preloader size='small'/>
)
```

Comment: Hey! Somehow I am only able to use an approved list of packages currently and this module is not yet in it. So I am trying to use the regular materializecss, which should work anyways since the circle preloader works..

Comment: if this answer helps you please mark as accepted, otherwise you should provide more details in your question